# Datatables responsive.hasHidden() returns true even if the table is not in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to build an app using Datatables responsive, and a button "View" on each recordthat can be accessed either in normal or in responsive mode.

The following is the layout for this in normal mode:

[image]

In responsive mode:

[image]

I initialized my datatables through the following:

```
const table = $("table.display").DataTable({
      responsive: {
        details: {
          type: "column",
          target: -1,
        },
      },
      columnDefs: [
        {
          className: "control",
          orderable: false,
          targets: -1,
        },
      ],
      bRetrieve: true,
    });
    table.column(0).visible(false);
    this.clickListener(table, this.route);
```

the `clickListener` function listens for the view button to be clicked, here are the code I implemented for it:

```
var self = this;
$(".display").on("click", "tbody tr td .view", function (e) {
  rowData = self.checkIfRowsHidden(table, this, e);
  console.log(rowData);
});
```

But since there were child rows in responsive mode I had to create a function to retrieve data based on it's current status, which is why I used `checkIfRowsHidden`. The following is the code for it:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (table.responsive.hasHidden()) {
      console.log(true);
      const parentRow = $(scope).closest("tr").prev()[0];
      return table.row(parentRow).data();
    } else {
      return table.row($(scope).closest("tr")).data();
    }
```

The problem I have is, whether I'm in responsive or normal mode, it always returns true, which is a big problem because then in normal mode it starts retrieving data for the row above. What seems to be the problem? There was a similar discussion [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61445/bug-responsive-hashidden) but it didn't solve it for me

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using a control column. However if you want the hide/show button on the right side, I believe you have to use the control column.
I think you have two options.

**Option 1**: Change the DataTables instantiation to put the button on the left, and leave checkIfRowsHidden how it is:

```
    const table = $("table.display").DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      bRetrieve: true
    });
```

**Option 2**: Change checkIfRowsHidden to look at the classes that DataTables assigns:

```
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    const tr = $(scope).closest("tr");
    if (tr.hasClass('child')) {
      console.log(true);
      tr = tr.prev();
    }
    return table.row(tr).data();
```